# How to display Softmax highest probability

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am running the following [code](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/pointnet.ipynb).
I am trying to display the probability of the predicted label next to the prediction but I have a hard time trying in doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't familiar with Keras hope it works.

```
data = test_dataset.take(1)

points, labels = list(data)[0]
points = points[:8, ...]
labels = labels[:8, ...]

# run test data through model
preds = model.predict(points)
print(preds)
preds = tf.reduce_max(preds, -1) #this line you need
print(preds)
preds = tf.math.argmax(preds, -1)
print(preds)

.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not run the code, but I beleive `preds` variable will be having all the probabilities.

For a particular input that you are trying to predict, if you want to see the maximum prediction value, you can do `max(pred)`.